# Hidden Message: Of Shapes and Numbers

Tags: visual

I've created a puzzle quite a while back, unfortunately not many people wanted to play so I'm posting here instead.

> The idea is that the image can be decipher to uncover a hidden message. The hint is given:
>
> [image]
>
> Hints: **“Like time, their true forms are revealed once they’re divided by their seats”**

The first step is to figure out how to read the numbers, Joe already figured one part of the first step. The answer of the puzzle will be in text form.

Hope you guys enjoy my game. Any comments on the puzzle is greatly welcome as well.

Comment: You should re-post here.

Comment: I'll freely admit, I'm completely lost on where to start on this one. I see no letters or message in the picture, just a geometric diagram of sorts. I agree with Matt that you should re-post the image here.

Comment: is this like that cicada 3301 cryptography game? (requiring resources beyond the image itself (like image manipulation software))

Comment: I have no idea where to start...

Comment: @generalcrispy it appears to be based on a clock (hence the "like time" part of the clue). I'm a bit too tired to think straight, but I'm fairly confident that's the starting point

Comment: Thanks for clearing up my question and for help me edit.

Comment: @moonRabbit should the clue read "their true **forms** are...", or "their true form **is**..." or is the wording absolutely correct?

Comment: @d'alar'cop no, all the information needed is inside the image itself. The question is more on how to get and use it.

Comment: @Joe ah, you're right. It's "their true forms are..." I'll edit the post. All the numbers need to be converted by using a common method.

Comment: Does the largest number being a multiple of 60 and 24 mean anything?

Comment: @warspyking not quite. Although there is a reason why the numbers becomes quite large but the fact that they're a multiple of 60 and 24 doesn't mean anything.

Comment: @moon 60 second in a min. 60 min in an hour. 24 hours in a day. I was thinking of time XD

Comment: @warspyking oh, I never thought of it that way lol. That's an interesting idea, using 'time' in that way. Maybe I'll try that for a different puzzle XD

Comment: One more thing I'm fairly sure is related (but I've just woken up so I'm still too sleepy :-P) is that the numbers in the first quarter (as on a clock face) are the smallest, and each quarter gets larger. Also, looking at individual digits, each quarter only uses a few (4, 5, 1 in lower left, then 3, 6 dominate lower right)

Comment: Can we get some kind of hint as to what kind of message is hidden? (is it text (shapes or ascii), it is a lat/long location,numerology) - anything?

Comment: @d'alar'cop the message is in text forms. Which means the final answer will be words.

Comment: Nice puzzle!...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As Joe commented, the numbers seem to get larger as you move around the circle's edge like a clock face. Then the "hint" says "divided by their seat". So if the numbers are getting divided by something, and what they're divided by gets bigger as you move around the circle, the seat must be something that gets bigger as you move around the circle.

Next, starting with the 18 and moving clockwise we can see that each number is divisible by its position in that circle. So that's probably what seat means- position.

Trying the same thing for the outermost rectangle, we start with the 6 and move clockwise and get the same divisibility property. Same for the triangle, starting 20, same again for inner rectangle, starting 13. I'm just going with points on the corner of a shape being members of that shape, points on the sides are ignored, because otherwise we don't get this property of being divisible by incrementing numbers

So going through and dividing, the numbers become:

> - Hexagon - 18, 1, 2, 2, 9, 20
> - Outer rectangle - 6, 18, 15, 13
> - Triangle - 20, 8, 5
> - Inner rectangle - 13, 15, 15, 14

One of those comments mentioned converting the numbers by "a common method" and... well, they're all less than 26 now! Let's try turning them into letters alphabetically:

> - Hexagon - RABBIT
> - Outer rectangle - FROM
> - Triangle - THE
> - Inner - MOON

Solution:

> Rabbit from the moon

Comment: Really nicely done. I couldn't quite piece it all together :-)

Comment: Awesomely done. You're absolutely correct, congratulation :)

Comment: That was great, well done!