# A puzzling image maze!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, mazes, imgur-maze

I was inspired by [Rainbow Road Rabbit Hole](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/24792/) to make a two-dimensional image maze where each image points to its neighboring rooms. Start here:

[image]

---

### Clarifications and corrections:

#### Reassembly

> "Either... or..." statements are inclusive or. This means that both sides can be true at the same time.

#### Half the Picture

> If you went directly to this room, you'll need to come back later.

#### Block Cipher

> The block on the right should be Nether Brick, not a Stone Pressure Plate.

#### Mind Games

> The location of the small circles within the big circles is irrelevant.

#### Ill Omens

> The first four characters of the fourth line should be at the end of the third line instead, and the first four characters of the third line should be copied to the beginning of the fourth line (so that there are twelve characters in line 3 and eight in line 4). [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6J9Pk.png) for a corrected version of these two lines. The corrected transcript for these lines is [here](http://pastebin.com/5K5kih7k).

#### Multiple Parts

> There is no wordplay involved. The letter counts for the left are (3,7,4,8) and for the right (3,8,2,3,5).

Comment: Pity I don't have time to work on this right now... Looks fun.

Comment: Don't think I'll be able to do this - I am colour blind and the line on the right looked black to me until I read all the text and closely inspected the line (probably due to the "data"). And the sudoku just looks lie a mess of yellow to me

Comment: OK, so fiddling with saturation and hue I can pick out most of the sudoku - could you tell me what colours make up the 2 in the bottom-right block please?

Comment: Do you encourage partial solutions, even if they just provide the code for one adjacent room?

Comment: @Sleafar: Thanks. I just wanted to make sure what the general consensus on such puzzles is. So they are more like solo expeditions rather than teamwork. And I guess the rules are loosened when there isn't a solution for some time. Good puzzle so far, by the way.

Comment: @MOehm If you wish to collaborate add to the community wiki post I made - but use spoilers :)

Comment: @MOehm Apparently I'm the only one wishing to spend some time on my own with this kind of puzzles, therefore forget what I said and post anything you like. In the meantime I'll try to find my way back from the endless recursive maze.

Comment: @MOehm If you want to bounce ideas around visit [puzzles-Etc](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37632/puzzles-etc)

Comment: Block cipher: Minecraft.

Comment: @Peanut: We've already solved that one. Even if we hadn't, that comment does not help us at all.

Comment: I'm just loving that this exists. I'm gonna take my time and get through it on my own (I hope). Excellent puzzle from what I've seen so far!

Comment: +1 +1 +1  How could I have missed that one? (Just found due to the new [12th fortnightly challange](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5084/fortnightly-topic-challenge-12-mazes))

Answer (score 41, accepted):

## Solved

**Map**:

> [image: EXAMPLE ROOM][image: right][image: COLLISIONS][image: right][image: REASSEMBLY][image: wall][image: ACCOLADES]
> [image: down][image: wall][image: wall][image: up]
>  [image: GET TWO FREE][image: wall][image: MIND GAMES][image: right][image: WHERE ARE YOU][image: right][image: ILL OMENS]
> [image: down][image: up][image: wall][image: wall]
>  [image: MAZES IN MAZES][image: right][image: HALF THE PICTURE][image: right][image: BACKTRACKING][image: right][image: GOAL IN SIGHT]
> [image: wall][image: down][image: wall][image: wall]
>  [image: MULTIPLE PARTS][image: left][image: BLOCK CIPHER][image: right][image: FIFTEEN PUZZLES][image: right][image: TAKING IT APART]

---

**Individual Puzzles**:

As per @Henkie's post, the second door from [EXAMPLE ROOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbcCr.png) **solved**

> On the first page, the right side is encoded as morse.
>  It reads SEVENBIGJSMALLASMALLBBIGA
>  Which leads to [7JabA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JabA.png) (COLLISIONS)

[COLLISIONS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JabA.png) **solved**

> Each paragraph describes one of the individuals who are particles...
>  1st [J/psi meson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%2fpsi_meson) **J**
>  2nd [proton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton) **p**
>  3rd [B meson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_meson) **B**
>  4th [Kaon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaon) **K**
>  5th [Lambda baryon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_baryon) Λ, wearing a belt: **A**
>  yielding [JpBKA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpBKA.png) (REASSEMBLY)

[REASSEMBLY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpBKA.png) **solved**

> The correct solution (from Henkie) was HAF/DCI/EBG.

[GET TWO FREE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Duh7m.png) **solved**

> There are three sudoku: a cyan one, a magenta one, and a yellow one
>  (blue=magenta+cyan; green=cyan+yellow; red=magenta+yellow; black=magenta+cyan+yellow).
>
> The exit wall is repeated cyan, magenta and yellow pixels (could there be three rooms or is that just a hint for the colours employed?)
>
> There is a grey 2 at the top-right of the bottom-right block  - do we need to also "get this free"?
>
>  If I got it all right, then all three are uniquely solvable with the grey 2, without it: Cyan has 38 solutions (only one has a 2 there, 20 have a 4, 11 have a 5, 6 have a 9); Magenta still has just the one solution; Yellow has 4 solutions, the other three having a 1 in the grey 2's place.
>
> The sudokus, with solutions using the grey 2 on the right.
>
> Cyan: .7..1.2.....7....86..592....52.348....1...3....468.12....361...1....7.....6.2..3.
>
> ```
> · 7 · | · 1 · | 2 · ·      4 7 9 | 8 1 3 | 2 6 5
> · · · | 7 · · | · · 8      2 3 5 | 7 4 6 | 9 1 8
> 6 · · | 5 9 2 | · · ·      6 1 8 | 5 9 2 | 4 7 3
> ------+-------+------      ------+-------+------
> · 5 2 | · 3 4 | 8 · ·      7 5 2 | 1 3 4 | 8 9 6
> · · 1 | · · · | 3 · ·      8 6 1 | 2 7 9 | 3 5 4
> · · 4 | 6 8 · | 1 2 ·      3 9 4 | 6 8 5 | 1 2 7
> ------+-------+------      ------+-------+------
> · · · | 3 6 1 | · · ·      9 8 7 | 3 6 1 | 5 4 2
> 1 · · | · · 7 | · · ·      1 2 3 | 4 5 7 | 6 8 9
> · · 6 | · 2 · | · 3 ·      5 4 6 | 9 2 8 | 7 3 1
> ```
>
> Magenta: .....2.1.136......7.451.6.....2..571...495...582..1.....5.497........846.4.8.....
>
> ```
> · · · | · · 2 | · 1 ·      9 5 8 | 6 7 2 | 4 1 3
> 1 3 6 | · · · | · · ·      1 3 6 | 9 8 4 | 2 5 7
> 7 · 4 | 5 1 · | 6 · ·      7 2 4 | 5 1 3 | 6 8 9
> ------+-------+------      ------+-------+------
> · · · | 2 · · | 5 7 1      4 9 3 | 2 6 8 | 5 7 1
> · · · | 4 9 5 | · · ·      6 7 1 | 4 9 5 | 3 2 8
> 5 8 2 | · · 1 | · · ·      5 8 2 | 7 3 1 | 9 6 4
> ------+-------+------      ------+-------+------
> · · 5 | · 4 9 | 7 · ·      8 6 5 | 1 4 9 | 7 3 2
> · · · | · · · | 8 4 6      2 1 9 | 3 5 7 | 8 4 6
> · 4 · | 8 · · | · · ·      3 4 7 | 8 2 6 | 1 9 5
> ```
>
> Yellow: ......6144....8.35213.6.....94..1...8.......6...8..49.....7.84.12.4....7745......
>
> ```
> · · · | · · · | 6 1 4      5 8 7 | 3 9 2 | 6 1 4
> 4 · · | · · 8 | · 3 5      4 6 9 | 7 1 8 | 2 3 5
> 2 1 3 | · 6 · | · · ·      2 1 3 | 5 6 4 | 7 8 9
> ------+-------+------      ------+-------+------
> · 9 4 | · · 1 | · · ·      3 9 4 | 6 2 1 | 5 7 8
> 8 · · | · · · | · · 6      8 5 1 | 9 4 7 | 3 2 6
> · · · | 8 · · | 4 9 ·      6 7 2 | 8 5 3 | 4 9 1
> ------+-------+------      ------+-------+------
> · · · | · 7 · | 8 4 ·      9 3 6 | 1 7 5 | 8 4 2
> 1 2 · | 4 · · | · · 7      1 2 8 | 4 3 6 | 9 5 7
> 7 4 5 | · · · | · · ·      7 4 5 | 2 8 9 | 1 6 3
> ```
>
> If we were to overlay those on the right there would be FIVE black numbers:
>
> ```
> . · · · | · · · | · · · 6
> 7 · · · | · · · | · · · ?
> @ · · · | 5 · · | · · · H
>   ------+-------+------
> I · · · | · · · | · · · Q
> R · · 1 | · · · | 3 · · Z
> [ · · · | · · · | · · · c
>   ------+-------+------
> d · · · | · · · | · · 2 l
> m · · · | · · · | · · · u
> v · 4 · | · · · | · · · ~
> ```
>
> All the letters on the right are 8 more (in ASCII) than those on the left, so the numbers 1,2,3,4,5 yield [TlXwC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlXwC.png) (MAZES IN MAZES)

[MAZES IN MAZES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlXwC.png) **solved**

> Note that you start by entering Red and inside Red you enter a Yellow then inside that Yellow you enter another copy of Yellow then pop back out of that Yellow into the previous Yellow then out of that Yellow back to the original Red then ... then you exit the maze from the original Red:
>  [image: path through the mazes]
>  yielding [Ue3b6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ue3b6.png)

[HALF THE PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ue3b6.png) **solved**

> XORing the Reassembly image with the Half image, we get [image: xored]. Reading off the red, green, and blue channels, we get:
>  [C1en2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1en2.png) (MIND GAMES)
>  [2bzyR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bzyR.png) (BACKTRACKING)
>  [k5E2V](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5E2V.png) (BLOCK CIPHER)

[MIND GAMES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1en2.png) **solved**

> This is a game of Mastermind: the blues represent misses, the reds are hits but in the wrong place, and the greens are hits but in the right place. The solution is [DtvqW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtvqW.png).

[WHERE ARE YOU?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtvqW.png) **solved**

> That $\oplus$ symbol is "xor" (the operation where you take the bits in either A or B but not both; if you're xoring several things together it doesn't matter what order you do them in.). The equation says that xoring all three of the rooms together gives us `4sP~u`; since you can undo an XOR with another XOR, I just XORed all three 5-char strings together to get [LahLf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LahLf.png).

[ILL OMENS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LahLf.png) **solved**

> These characters are a Unicode text file reinterpreted as extended ASCII. Reading off the Unicode characters, most are from the Sutton Sign Language block; these, plus modifiers to label capital and lowercase, spell [r2HDr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2HDr.png).

[ACCOLADES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2HDr.png) **solved**

> These are all descriptions of Stack Exchange badges! The badges, in order, are Revival, Research Assistant, and Populist. Extracting the letters, makes "ARAPANOVECV - 6". Applying a Caesar shift of -6 results in "ULUJUHIPYWP", which is the red key.

[BACKTRACKING](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bzyR.png) **solved**

> There is a gray character hidden (or sometimes not hidden) in each of the puzzles on this path. Those characters, in reverse order, are [Qv2RX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvR2X.png) (GOAL IN SIGHT).

[GOAL IN SIGHT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvR2X.png) **solved**

> The images refer to other "visual" puzzles, the numbers refer to puzzle solutions (from left to right):
>
>  H : [A well balanced puzzle: Logic puzzle(s) in visual disguise](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6453/a-well-balanced-puzzle-logic-puzzles-in-visual-disguise)
>  P : [Perplexing Fireworks](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/17212/perplexing-fireworks)
>  B : [Hidden Message: Of Shapes and Numbers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2434/hidden-message-of-shapes-and-numbers)
>  W : [Lepidopterology needed!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16881/lepidopterology-needed)
>  S : [The Writing's on the Wall](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/17409/the-writings-on-the-wall)
>  B : [A hunt for long forgotten treasure ...but beware the pirate's curse!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/13303/a-hunt-for-long-forgotten-treasure-but-beware-the-pirates-curse)
>  D : [Find the secret phrase in this encrypted image (Part 4)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15278/find-the-secret-phrase-in-this-encrypted-image-part-4)
>  R : [The Musing Of the Eggs](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/29571/the-musing-of-the-eggs)
>  B : [The markings of Mictal](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/28308/the-markings-of-mictal)
>  U : [This is important. I need you to listen…](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/28494/this-is-important-i-need-you-to-listen)
>  O : [Little bits of food](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/32046/little-bits-of-food)
>
>  So the green key is HPBWSBDRBUO.

[BLOCK CIPHER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5E2V.png) **solved**

> This is a screenshot from Minecraft. Each block in Minecraft has a "data value", a number used internally to store what type of block is in which location. Reading the data values of the blocks in a row out as ASCII gives [14k9p](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14k9p.png) (MULTIPLE PARTS).

[BLOCK CIPHER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5E2V.png) (solution 2)

> If you read the IDs of the lower blocks you get "Red5T0nE". Using a DES cipher on the base64 sign text with this as the key gives you [nCXwy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCXwy.png) (FIFTEEN PUZZLES).

[MULTIPLE PARTS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14k9p.png) **solved**

> Both clues refer to Stack Exchange puzzles that have been duplicated in format by many people. The first refers to [The hangman game backward](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11281/the-hangman-game-backward) and the second refers to [The Security to the Party](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3981/the-security-to-the-party). Extracting the letters we're told to from each of the question titles, we get EWNCGGMESRO+5. Applying a Caesar shift of +5 makes JBSHLLRJXWT, which is the blue key.

[FIFTEEN PUZZLES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCXwy.png) **solved**

> Each of the puzzles has a 4x4 grid with a square missing in the bottom right corner. These can be treated as scrambled [15-puzzles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle), and the arrows here tell us how they were scrambled. Undoing the scrambles, we get... nothing really. But, if you *then* undo the scramble of ALL the solved puzzles using the last arrow as a reference, you get: [image: unscrambled]
> This looks like 4w9g8, and in fact [it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4w9g8.png). (TAKING IT APART)

[TAKING IT APART](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4w9g8.png) **solved**

> Deciphering "APLASTICBAG" with the keys yields:
>  red: GERRYMANDER
>  green: TAKEASFLAGS
>  blue: ROTTHIRTEEN
>  So we gerrymander to put 3 of four regions in Greens favour (currently way behind Red in the polls)
>  Then treat the lines as flags as per semaphore in the direction their region's number is facing
>  Then rot 13 the letters
>  Yielding:
>  [image]
>  Reading those in the direction of the region numbers gives us:
>  **GOOD JOB YOU HAVE FINISHED THE MAZE** (!)

Answer (score 16):

On the first page, the right side

> It is encoded as morse.
>  It reads SEVENBIGJSMALLASMALLBBIGA
>  Which leads to https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JabA.png

Collisions:

> Probably about quarks.
>  Number 2 is about the proton.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, and great find!

Comment: (Also, we're talking about this in the [Puzzles Etc](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37632/puzzles-etc) chat room - feel free to join in the conversation!)

Comment: Thanks! I have been following the conversation but was unable to join because of the reputation requirement.

Comment: You should be able to join now, the requirement is 20 rep.